# show and hide components versus destroy and recreate component

Tags: angular, performance

I have a multi-step form. I have 6-7 steps and right now i have designed the system like each step is a component. When user switches to next step, the previous step component is destroyed and new step component is initialized. So i have totally 6-7 components. Is show and hiding components is better or destroying and recreating the component is better.

Comment: first, explain what is your concept of "better"

Comment: I have explained how i have implemented and alternate for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably destroy and create...

Angular accesses the shadow dom when it instantiates new components / the contents of components, which is far less burdening for performance:

> Shadow DOM refers to the ability of the browser to include a subtree of DOM elements into the rendering of a document, but not into the main document DOM tree...... Changes to the DOM usually cause re-rendering of the page. [Ref](https://vuejsfeed.com/blog/learn-the-differences-between-shadow-dom-and-virtual-dom)

Also, if you only show and hide, then you are going to miss out on all the handy lifecycle hooks which the angular framework provides for you around the "Showing / Rendering" of a component on screen; `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterViewInit` etc.

---

Just a further note that hiding / showing an element via css does **not** manipulate the DOM, the main reason I am recommending is for the lifecycle hooks and that when removing shadow dom content, it is less burdening performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use :

- console.time()
- console.profile()
- performance.now()

to calculate the performance and compare the two solutions.

You'll find below examples of use :

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#time

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#profile

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now